# Resize image to current text height using CSS

Tags: css

**Context**: I am trying to insert inline images of equations (PNG files) seamlessly into a webpage. I am aware that this has already been done before, but I'm using this as a learning project. Thus I am not interested in libraries that display math, but rather the general answer to this question.

I'd like the images to naturally scale their height to match to some percentage of the *current* text height with a css style. I'm a neophyte at web design, but it seems like I should be able to include a style that looks something like:

```
height: 80% * parent.text_height
```

Is this possible with pure CSS?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ems are a *relative* units of measurement which is dependent on the text size of the parent element.  One em is approximately the distance between lines of text.  Therefore, you could try:

```
height: .8em;
```

But be aware that inline elements (like a plain old `img` tag) don't accept height specifications.

Comment: This works perfectly, in fact it does better than you said. Putting a style change in `<img ... style="height:.8em">` does exactly what I think it should (using Chromium 20.0.1132.47). Is this something that is not browser compatible?

Comment: Using ems should be very well supported by browsers.  Browsers aren't *supposed* to accept height specifications on elements with `display:inline;` (like `spans` or `strong`s).  But any element can be changed to `display:block;`; there are other implications to that, though.